# Как поставить Stripe первым, PayPal вторым при выборе оплаты Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, stripe

На странице [оформления заказа](https://israel-escorts.com/en/checkout/) первый идет PayPal, затем идет Stripe. Как их поменять местами, чтобы Stripe был первый и выбран по умолчанию?

[image: o]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В настройках Woocommerce --> Платежи, можно перетащить Stripe выше и сохранить, однако PayPal все равно выбран по умолчанию, хотя стоит ниже теперь.

Решаем таким кодом jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                        jQuery('#payment_method_paypal').removeAttr('checked');
                        jQuery('#payment_method_stripe').attr('checked', 'checked');
                    });
```